# Insert Derived class as Base Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my current solution we're using the `Entity Framework (4.0)`. I have model that is mapped to database. In that model i have an `objectType` named '`Document`' which is mapped to the table '`Document`'.

In my solution I have the object `ExtDocument` which inherits from `Document`. ExtDocument contains some extra properties which provide extra information but `don't have any influence on the existing properties  of the baseclass.`

My main object used throughout the application is `ExtDocument`.
As it may happen we want to write a `Document NOT ExtDocument`. To our database
So i thought to use the following code:

```
dbContext.Document.AddObject((Document) doc);
```

or

```
dbContext.Document.AddObject((doc As Document));
```

But in both instances an exception is thrown that there is no mapping for `ExtDocument`. Is there a way to write the baseclass to the database `without cloning` the object first?

**Note 1** `ExtDocument` is the only type that will be deriving from `Document`

**Note 2** I've come across many questions with a slight reference to my problem but none supplied a solution or explained why i couldn't do it (without cloning).

examples:

[metadata-information-not-found-while-using-ef4s-poco-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247891/metadata-information-not-found-while-using-ef4s-poco-template)

[ef-mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350514/ef-mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype-error)

[map-derived-type-to-the-same-table-in-ef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854327/map-derived-type-to-the-same-table-in-ef)

[how-to-properly-display-or-save-inheriting-classes-into-database-with-entity-fra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747163/how-to-properly-display-or-save-inheriting-classes-into-database-with-entity-fra) <= Answerless

**NOTE On Duplicate:**

My issue does NOT occur upon instantiating a new class of the derived type. It only occurs upon saving to database

Comment: When the exception occurs is irrelevant, read the entire Q&A. It is simply not supported by Entity Framework to derive from entities and use those derived classes with your context, as stated in linked duplicate. Use composition instead.

Comment: You still need to clone the derived object, but there is a built in function that does that. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @CodeCaster isn't that the "wrong use" of composition? (according to .net standards) because `ExtDocument is a Document` but `ExtDocument has no document 'as his property'`. Same as `Car is a vehicle` but a `Car has no vehichles 'as his property'`. (Although i won't deny that your solution could work)

Comment: Depends on your domain, if it really is an "is-a" relation then yeah, it's unfortunate that you have to do an "improper" workaround because the proper way won't work.